# access data using docker jupyter notebooks with gpu support on google cloud

Tags: docker, tensorflow, jupyter

I have followed link :
https://blog.paperspace.com/jupyter-notebook-with-a-gpu-the-easy-way/

now my data in cloud is in folder ~/projects/tf-example/data , how do i access this data in my jupyter notebook ?
I saw some option to mount volume using docker cmd,but still not sure to access from notebook ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it,followed this link :
https://www.dataquest.io/blog/docker-data-science/

and it worked .

use this cmd,lets say locally ur files is in location ~/projects:

sudo nvidia-docker run --rm --name tf-notebook -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -v ~/projects:/notebooks/ gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu jupyter notebook --allow-root